# 2d array Program for an assignment should be a simple fix, the goal is to get through the array and change all 1s to 7s no idea whats going wrong

Tags: java, arrays

This is a program that is used to go through an array and change all 1 's that are connected to each-other to the number 7.

Iam having an issue with the program going to the far right side of the array and instead of continuing downward to complete the change to the other 1's it stops.

The program compiles fine with 0 errors.
Earlier today I was running into an "out of bounds exception" error but fixed it by adding +1 or -1 to the col / row variables.

Why is it that the code stops working when it hits the far right column of the array?

```
  `public static void run(){ 
    int[][]nums = createPath(); 
    finder(nums);   
    createPath(); 
    printPath(nums); 
} 


public static void finder(int[][] path){ 


    int row = 0; 
    int col = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < path.length+1; i++) {
        // right control movement
        if(path[row][col+1]==1) { //col + 1 
            //path[row][col+1]==1
            col++; 

            path[row][col]=7; 

        } 
        // downward control
        else if(path[row+1][col]==1) { // row + 1 

            row++; 

            path[row][col]=7; 

        } 
        // left control
        else if(path[row][col-1]==1) { // col - 1 

            col-- ; 

            path[row][col]=7; 

        } 

    }
    System.out.println("congrats big man"); 

} 
public static int[][] createPath(){ 
    int[][] path = { 
            {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, 
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, 
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}, 
            {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}}; 

    return path; 

} 

public static void printPath(int[][] path) { 

    int[][]balls = createPath(); 

    for(int i=0; i<path.length; i++) { 

        for(int j=0; j<path[i].length; j++) { 

            System.out.print(path[i][j]+ " "); 

        } 

        System.out.println(); 

    } 

    System.out.println(); 

} 
   `
```

Comment: Execution begins with the `public static void main (String [] args)` method. What does that method do?  It calls `createPath ()`. There are no instructions to follow after that, so the program terminates normally.  And, by the way, in `main`, the `int[][]` returned by `createPath()` is ignored.

Comment: completely forgot about the main method, its not used and I've just been executing the run method specifically.

Comment: By the way, have you tried running this in a debugger? You can set breakpoints. When code execution reaches a breakpoint, it halts. You can inspect variables, and run the code one-step-at-a-time.  Another way is to insert `System.println (` calls to display where the program is and the values of selected variables.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Please also fine polish your indentation to make your code still easier or us to read and see what could be wrong. I believe your BlueJ can indent the code for you.

Comment: Will `path` always be a "square array"? (i.e., number of rows == number of columns).

Comment: Your 2D array is 20 by 20. So `path.length` is 20. So `for (int i = 0; i < path.length+1; i++)` makes the program go 21 times through the loop. That doesn’t suffice for all the 1s. Also after you go down you sometimes need to left, sometimes right.

Comment: Do you get an exception? If you do, the question should have a copy of the stack trace.  It looks to me like your code could throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. For example, if the current column is the rightmost column, and you check the next column to the right.  It's made worse with the `+1` in ` for (int i = 0; i < path.length+1; i++)`

Comment: By the way, since you are new here, you might want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and pages they link to.

Comment: I get no exception, it compiles fine just stops changing ones to sevens on the 20th column and 3rd row. it changes that 1 to a seven and than instead of continuing downward it stops. I have removed the +1 from path.length and it still works fine.

Comment: I wonder if it does throw an exception, but you are not seeing it. It might have something to do with the way you are running the code. Try adding this line to your code early, where it is sure to be executed: `System.err.println ("I can see stderr.");`

Comment: I added the code provided to two different places to test, 1 to the very top of the finder method and one to the very top of the printPath method, the text "I can see stderr." has appeared twice in the place errors typically show up but nothing else

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line: `for (int i = 0; i < path.length+1; i++) {`

When I first saw that line, I thought it was iterating through each row of `path`.  But, it causes your program to look for `path.length` *cells*, not rows, then quits. Unless the path is straight down, there are more cells, likely many more, in the path than `path.length`.

I suggest the following changes to your code:

- Decide on how it will be determined that the end of the path has been reached.
- Replace the `for` loop with a `while` loop or a `do while` loop, using the terminating condition. This is because the number of cells to be marked will be unknown when the loop begins.
- Alternatively, use `while (true)` and have a `break` inside the loop when the terminating condition is reached.
- Move `path[row][col] = 7` to the top of the loop, before the `if` statements that check if the next move is right, down, or left. Alternatively, move it after those `if` blocks. For simplicity, it is better to have it in one place.
- The *only* content of the right / down / left `if` blocks should be to change `row`  or `col`, and possibly to detect the terminating condition.
- Add guard `if` statements to be sure checking the adjacent cells does not go out of bounds.

```
boolean advance = true;
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
while ( advance ) { 
    path [row][col] = 7;
    if (path [row][col+1] == 1) { col++; } // right
    else if (path[row][col-1] == 1) { col--; } // left
    else if (path[row+1][col] == 1) { row++; } // down
    else { advance = false; }
}
```

I did not include the guard checking. Without them, this code will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` condition for most paths. You can add the guard conditions to the `if` statements using `&&` before the `path[` part.

This code assumes `path [0][0]` will initially have a value of `1`. It assumes there will be no turn in the up direction.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will implement this into my code asap.

Comment: It is indeed throwing the out of bounds exception, I have an idea of using  the if statement to check if its either a 1, 0 or 7. Do you have a possibly better / more efficient idea?

Comment: @Khariu  The `if` statement guards would be something like this: `if (col + 1 < path[row].length` for "move right" check. For "move left", `if (col - 1 >= 0`. For "move down", `if (row + 1 < path.length`.  Combine the guard clauses with the appropriate `if` / `else if`.  For example, `if (col + 1 < path[row].length && path[row][col + 1])`. The guard clause should be on the left side of the `&&` because you need short circuit evaluation.

Comment: I've implemented this and it has solved the out of bounds exception, but now the ones stop changing to sevens after the first digit, do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @Khariu do you mean it halts after only one iteration?  No, I don't know why that is happening. (But, I have not actually compiled or run the code.)   If it halts after one iteration, the bounds exception problem might not actually have been solved. In any case, check / debug your current code. If you don't figure it out, we might want to see it, which would require a new question.

Comment: No, for some reason it completes the change to the first cell and completes the change to the second cell changing two 1's to 7's total. I will go through the debug process again tomorrow and see if I can solve it myself.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... the goal is to get through the array and change all 1s to 7s no idea whats going wrong ..."*

You'll need a *loop* for each array.

```java
void f(int[][] x) {
    int i, n;
    for (int[] a : x)
        for (i = 0, n = x.length; i < n; i++)
            if (a[i] == 1) a[i] = 7;
}
```

Comment: Im not allowed to hard code / brute force this assignment. Also that for loop just doesnt work in my coding software, my school has us using the BlueJ application.

Comment: @Khariu , I don't understand your objection. The question header says the assignment is to change all `1` to `7`. The best way to do that is to go cell-by-cell.  Now, if there is a restriction that all the cells with value `1`  have to be contiguous, and, once started, you are allowed to move only to an orthogonally adjacent cell that has value `1`, you should edit the question to state that. Do not rely on us inferring that from your code sample.

Comment: Very sorry, Iam new to all this stuff, I will edit the original question ASAP.

Comment: @Khariu, this doesn't compile in _BlueJ_?